# Dropdown list show only one letter Prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a prestashop module.in my controller `renderForm` i have drop down list to load week days.but it showing only first letter of the day.

```
    public function renderForm() {

$days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

    'input' => [

                    [
                      'type' => 'select',
                        'lang' => true,
                        'required' => true,
                        'label' => $this->l('WeekDay'),
                        'name' => 'weekday',
                        'options' => [
                          'query' => $days,

                        ],

                    ],
         ]
    }
```

Showing like this

[image]

Inspect Element

[image: Inspect]

Comment: check the console, how it's showing there. May be some Js or CSS hiding that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `query` value should be like below format as per prestashop 1.7 documentation.

```
$days = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,        // The value of the 'value' attribute of the <option> tag.
    'name' => $this->trans('Monday', array(), 'Admin.International.Feature') // The value of the text content of the  <option> tag.
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => $this->trans('Tuesday', array(), 'Admin.International.Feature')
  ),
);
```